# Big O notation (Algorithms)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Hi I am new to Big O Notation and having trouble specifying big O for the following if someone could kindly explain to me how to work it out please

```
int sum=1;
for(int count=n; count>0; count/=2) {
    sum=sum*count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As each time `count` is divided by 2, it will be `Theta(log n)` (from `n` to `0`). Hence, it is in `O(log(n))` as well.

Comment: How come theta is an answer for Big O?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Based on the `Theta` definition, if `f(n)` is in `Theta(g(n))`, it will be in `O(g(n))` as well.

Comment: In this case, it's true. My point was to indicate that in your answer as well, which you did.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri all the time, it's true. As I said, it backs to the definition of `Theta` and `O`, and it can be proved mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, the code will run once, so for it, the complexity is O(1).
In second line a for loop will run until count > 0 and we can see that it will be divided by 2 every time loop runs and so it will just go on continuously infinite times. So basically, you cannot apply Big O notation on an infinite loop. And so also you cannot apply big O to the code inside the loop as well. So if there exist any O(infinite) then it could be an answer, but it won't exist. So you cannot define time complexity until and unless n<=0. if n<=0 then only the code will run once and complexity will be O(1).

Answer (score 1):

*count* gets halved per each iteration. If `n = 64`:

```
step1 => count = 64
step2 => count = 32
step3 => count = 16
...
```

Therefore, its worst case scenario has a `O(log n)` time complexity.

In this case, however, your loop's body has a constant number of operations, therefore, best, worst, and average case scenarios are same, and:

```
Ω(log n) = Θ(log n) = O(log n)
```